# filtrar array por id y dejar el que mas datos almacena

Tags: javascript, array, filtro

el array que tengo tiene el siguiente formato:

```
array = [{id:1, data:[array(1)]},
         {id:1, data:[array(2)]},
         {id:1, data:[array(3)]},
         {id:2, data:[array(1)]},
         {id:2, data:[array(2)]},
         {id:2, data:[array(3)]},
         {id:2, data:[array(4)]},
         {id:3, data:[array(1)]},
         {id:4, data:[array(1)]},
         {id:4, data:[array(2)]}]
```

se almacena de forma incremental la información dentro de data y me gustaría poder quedarme solo con el que tiene mas data por cada id.

la idea final es la siguiente:

```
newArray = [{id:1, data:[array(3)]},
         {id:2, data:[array(4)]},
         {id:3, data:[array(1)]},
         {id:4, data:[array(2)]}]
```

he intentado filtrando con Math.max() pero no he logrado obtener el resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pruebe este código

```js
var array = [{id:1, data:[1]},
         {id:1, data:[1,1]},
         {id:1, data:[1,1,1]},
         {id:2, data:[1]},
         {id:2, data:[1,1]},
         {id:2, data:[1,1,1]},
         {id:2, data:[1,1,1,1]},
         {id:3, data:[1]},
         {id:4, data:[1]},
         {id:4, data:[1,1]}];
var newArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  var current = newArray.find(x => x.id === array[i].id)
  if (current === undefined){
    newArray.push(array[i]);
  }else{
    if (current.data.length < array[i].data.length){
      const currentIndex = newArray.indexOf(current);
      newArray.splice(currentIndex, 1, array[i])
    }
  }
}


console.log(newArray)
```

Lo que hago es recorrer el arreglo original y si no existe ninguno con ese id en el nuevo array (se verifica con el método find que devuelve *undefined* si no se cumple el criterio) agrego el elemento actual, de existir uno verifico quien tiene un array de mayor longitud, si el nuevo tiene mayor longitud que le viejo lo sustituyo con el método *splice* Saludos

Comment: Te mereces el cielo, muchas gracias por dar con la solución.

Comment: Por nada, me alegro que haya resuelto su problema